# Creating a list in python from items in an imported list causes the code to stop

Tags: python, list, import

I'm trying to create a list of random items from a big list in another file, and it seems to fail to make this list. Can someone point out what I'm missing please. I have tried to change the way the list is made, using i += 1 and the works. The way I've kept is the way it works when the list was used in the same file

'''

```
from classes.item_list import items
from classes.game import Player
import random

full_list = []
goal = input("How many items to scavenge? : ")
while len(full_list) != goal:
    full_list.append(items[random.randrange(0, len(items))])

player_count = int(input("How many players?"))
```

'''

the output is "How many items to scavenge? : "
and will not carry on after an input

In the same folder I have a classes folder with an **init**.py file, and the item_list.py file with the large list inside it

Comment: `int(input("How many items to scavenge? : "))` Without it's a string and can never work

Comment: whats item here?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`goal` is read with `input`, so it's a string, it will never be equal to a list's length. You need to convert it to an `int` if you're going to compare them. E.g.:

```
goal = int(input("How many items to scavenge? : "))
```